# Syntax of $http in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, http, syntax

Can someone please explain this to me:

```
.
.
.
$http(req)
.then(function()
{
.
.
.
```

What does "dot then" mean?
In general I find it hard to understand the syntax of AngularJS, and it does not appear to be explained anywhere. Can anyone direct me to somewhere it is actually described for newbees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$http returns angularjs promise https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Main difference from native Promise is that you dont need to call scope digest manually.